# How can you input text into an input element without using send keys in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with a website where send_keys sometimes works and sometimes doesn't (I have no idea why). Sometimes it sends keys then I try a few hours later and it doesn't work anymore. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to send text/numbers into a input element WITHOUT using send_keys.

For example, would it be possible to input text into the following element without using send_keys:

```
<input _ngcontent-coh-c546="" type="text" name="tag" maxlength="25" placeholder="Tags" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add more details to your question such as your python script.

Comment: Have you ever tried pyautogui https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Comment: You probably can't input anything without using send_keys

Comment: I found an article which uses JavaScript for the purpose. [Click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-input-text-in-the-text-box-without-calling-the-sendkeys-using-selenium#:~:text=We%20can%20input%20text%20in,as%20parameter%20to%20the%20method.).

Comment: @Flow Would using pyautogui require my mouse to input text? I want to be able to run my python script in the backround/having my automated browser minimized.

Comment: @Zero Would you know where I could get a similar process but written in Python?

Comment: I can be written in Python using `driver.execute_script()`.

Comment: @Zero This true in my answer was the way I correctly used that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work effectively and faster compared to send_key

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value='What ever you want to be typed here'")
```